# Invariance of Brownian motion under orthogonal transformations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\left(B_t\right)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ be an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion with start at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $A$ be an orthogonal $n \times n$ real matrix. I'm trying to show that $AB$ is again an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion. I've succeeded in showing that each component is a one-dimensional Brownian motion, but I'm having a hard time showing that the components are independent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which characterizations of a Brownian motion do you know?

Comment: @saz: A one-dimensional Brownian motion $(B_t)$ with start at $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies four criteria: (1) $B_0 = x$, (2) $t \mapsto B_t$ is continuous, (3) If $0 \leq s \leq t$, $B_{t - s} \sim N(\mu=0, \sigma^2=t-s)$, (4) If $0 \leq t_0 \leq t_1 \leq \cdots \leq t_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then the increments $B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i - 1}}$ are independent.

An $n$-dimensional Brownian motion with start at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector consisting of $n$ independent one-dimensional Brownian motions with starts at $x_1, \dots, x_n$, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set $W_t := A \cdot B_t$ where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

1. Since $W_0=A \cdot x$ we see that $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ starts at $A \cdot x$.
2. As $t \mapsto B_t$ is continuous, we find that $t \mapsto A \cdot B_t$ is continuous.
3. Let $0 \leq s \leq t$. Then, $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \xi^T \cdot (W_t-W_s)} = \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \xi^T (A \cdot (B_t-B_s))} = \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, (A^T\xi)^T \cdot B_{t-s}} \end{align*}$$ for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Here we used the stationarity of the increments of $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$. As $B_{t-s} \sim N(0,(t-s) I_n)$, we get $$\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \xi^T \cdot (W_t-W_s)} = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} (t-s) |A^T \cdot \xi|^2 \right).$$ It follows straight from the orthogonality of $A$ that $|A^T \cdot \xi|=|\xi|$. Hence, $$\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \xi^T \cdot (W_t-W_s)} = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} (t-s) |\xi|^2 \right). \tag{1}$$ This shows that $W_{t-s} \sim W_t-W_s \sim N(0,(t-s) I_n)$.
4. Since $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion, the increments $$B_{t_1}-B_{t_0}, \ldots,B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}}$$ are independent. Obviously, this implies that $$A (B{t_1}-B_{t_0}),\ldots,A(B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}})$$ are independent. Hence, $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has independent increments.

Comment: Thank you. $B_t = \left[B_t^{(1)}, \dots, B_t^{(n)}\right]^T$. You've shown that for each $k \in \{1,\dots, n\}$, the component $(B_t^{(k)})_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a one-dimensional Brownian motion. But in order to show that $(B_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a Brownian motion, you still need to show that the components are independent.

Comment: Still, in order to satisfy the definition of an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion, $W_t$'s components must be independent. How can I see this?

Comment: @EvanAad If a process satisfies the properties (1)-(4), it is already a (multi-dimensional) Brownian motion; there is nothing left to prove. Note that I did *not* prove (1)-(4) for each component $(W_t^{(j)})_t$, but for the "whole" process $(W_t)_t$. (However, the independence of the components follows basically from (1); if you split it up into the components, you see that $$\mathbb{E}\exp \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \imath \xi_j (W_t^{(j)}-W_s^{(j)} \right) = \prod_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}\exp \left( \imath \xi_j (W_t^{(j)}-W_s^{(j)}) \right).$$ Using the independence of the increments finishes the proof.

Comment: If you want to see the proof, I can add it. But this has nothing to do with this particular Brownian motion given in your question; it is a general property of Brownian motion.

Comment: Yes, could you add it please?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found the proof in Schilling & Partzsch's "Brownian Motion" (de Gruyter, 2012) as Corollary 2.15, p. 16. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, exactly; could you have told this reference. (But you are not from Dresden, are you?)

Comment: No, I'm not. But I grew up on Erich Kaestner's children's books. He was from Dresden, wasn't he?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, indeed. :)

Comment: Why do you compute $\mathbb E[e^{i\xi^T(W_t-W_s)}]$ and not $\mathbb E[e^{\xi^T(W_t-W_s)}]$ ? Because if the generating moment function is $e^{\frac{1}{2}(t-s)|\xi|^2}$ this will prove that $W_t-W_s\sim N(0,(t-s)I_n)$ as well, no ? (I'm always confuse when I have to compute generating moment function of characteristic function)

Comment: @user657324 Well, yes, you can also compute the moment generating function. In general, it's better to consider the characteristic function since this does not require existence of (exponential) moments.